# Variable referenced instead of copied

Tags: python

When I run the code below it removes `deleted_partner` from `B`. But as it removes it from `B` it also removes it from `A`. So that when I try to remove it from `A` the program crashes. What is the problem?

```
for deleted_partner in self.list_of_trading_partners: 
    B = A[:]
    print("t", deleted_partner)
    print(B[self.ID].list_of_trading_partners)
    B[self.ID].list_of_trading_partners.remove(deleted_partner)
    Round_neo_classic(B)
    Round_costs(B)
    if B[self.ID].final_good > reference_value:
        print("d", deleted_partner)
        print(A[self.ID].list_of_trading_partners)
        A[self.ID].list_of_trading_partners.remove(deleted_partner)
```

Output:

```
('t', 1)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
('d', 1)
[2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: is it python 3 or do you have a custom print function ?

Comment: `print("Fine in Py2 too")` because these brackets just group and have no effect here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B=A[:]` does copy **only** the list, but **not** it's contents. `B[self.ID]` and `A[self.ID]` still reference the same object, only `A` and `B` are different.

You might way to explicitly copy all the elements of the list too - [copy.deepcopy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) can do this. But beware: deepcopy copies *everything* - it looks like you only want to copy the `list_of_trading_partners`, so you should probably write a `__deepcopy__` method on whatever class `A[self.ID]` is that does just that.

Answer (score 2):

You're not removing from B or A, but from `A[some_ID].list_of_trading_partners` and `B[some_ID].list_of_trading_partners`. `[:]` only makes a "shallow copy" of the list, in that it creates a new, separate list, but the elements contained in that list (one of which `list_of_trading_partners` is an attribute of) are not copied but referenced. Perhaps the `copy` module and its `deepcopy` function can help you?

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not put the real list is hard to do tests, buy you can try with copy.copy or copy.deepcopy

```
import copy

for deleted_partner in self.list_of_trading_partners: 
    B = copy.copy(A)
    print("t", deleted_partner)
    print(B[self.ID].list_of_trading_partners)
    B[self.ID].list_of_trading_partners.remove(deleted_partner)
    Round_neo_classic(B)
    Round_costs(B)
    if B[self.ID].final_good > reference_value:
        print("d", deleted_partner)
        print(A[self.ID].list_of_trading_partners)
        A[self.ID].list_of_trading_partners.remove(deleted_partner)
```

Comment: This indeed is a workaround, but I think the OP is not the only one to wonder about, as the splice operator used in that way _does_ produce a copy.